# Do promotions dicount work on special prices?

Tags: magento-1.9

I made a general promotion in Catalog Price Rules with 10% dicount. Now for some reason the tier price table disappears. I read somewhere that dicount from promotions is not calculate on special prices. Is that true?

How could i apply the dicount on all tier prices also?

System: Magento ver. 1.9.2.2

Thank you very much.

Comment: by default in magento , we can apply `tier prices/special prices or catalog prce rule` , both will not apply for product. which one will give high discount , that one will apply.....

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Sorry.

Comment: i means either you can use `tier prices/special prices or catalog prce rule` , you cant apply both for a product at a time....

Comment: Ah okay. I got it. Do you have any idea why the tierpirces table dissapears and i cant use tear prices anymore. I want the dicount to be applied (on single account)but also tier pice when someone order bigger amounts.

Comment: are you telling its disappear from frontend, also you want to give tier prices discount only for one customer, also if some one want to order for huge amount, you want to give discount for that customer ?

Answer (score 0):

No, It will not work. you can use either `tier prices/special prices` or `catalog prce rule` , you cant apply both for a product at a time.... which one give more discount, that discount display in site.....